# What is the command to remove all files but not directories?

Tags: command-line, files, delete, rm

Let's say I have a directory tree like this:

```
FOLDER:
    file1
    file2
    file3
    Subfolder1:
        file1
        file2
    Subfolder2:
        file1
        file2
```

If I used `rm -r FOLDER/*`, everything in FOLDER would be deleted including sub-directories. How can I delete all files in FOLDER and in its sub-directories without deleting actual directories?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

What you're trying to do is recursive deletion. For that you need a recursive tool, such as `find`.

```
find FOLDER -type f -delete
```

Answer (score 15):

With `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar  ## Enables recursive globbing
for f in FOLDER/**/*; do [[ -f $f ]] && echo rm -- "$f"; done
```

Here iterating over the glob expanded filenames, and removing only files.

The above is dry-run, if satisfied with the changes to be made, remove `echo` for actual removal:

```
for f in FOLDER/**/*; do [[ -f $f ]] && rm -- "$f"; done
```

Finally, unset `globstar`:

```
shopt -u globstar
```

---

With `zsh`, leveraging glob qualifier:

```
echo -- FOLDER/**/*(.)
```

`(.)` is glob qualifier, that limits the glob expansions to just regular files.

The above will just print the file names, for actual removal:

```
rm -- FOLDER/**/*(.)
```

Comment: +1 for zsh globbing. More people should be aware of the awesome things zsh can do.

Answer (score 11):

If your version of `find` doesn't support `-delete` you can use the following to delete every file in the current directory and below.

```
find . ! -type d -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Comment: `-exec rm {} +` would be faster, especially if there are lots of files.

Comment: And `find . ! -type d -exec rm {} +` removes sym links as well.

Comment: @muru: If a particular implementation of `find` doesn't support `-delete` it probably doesn't support `-exec ... {} +` either. The recommended way to deal with that is `find ... -print0 | xargs -r0 rm` (if one expects many potential matches).

Comment: @DavidFoerster not really. `-exec ... {} +` is POSIX, but `-delete` isn't. (Neither is `-print0`, by the way.)

Comment: @muru: Fair enough. I've encountered at least two non-POSIX `find` implementations that supported `-print0` but not `-exec ... {} +` (I don't remember about `-delete` though). One was on OS X, the other on Solaris (a few years ago on a very conservatively updated system). You can also substitute `-print0` with `-printf '%p\0'`. Anyway, this is Ask*Ubuntu* and not [Unix.SE] and Ubuntu uses GNU find since forever.

Comment: One that is even faster due to not forking for every rm: find . ! -type d -print0|xargs -0 -n50 rm -f .  That will delete 50 filenames at a time, and delimit with \0 just in case some filenames have spaces or other characters.